# Python storing a sting + variable + string into a variable

Tags: python, variables, text

I have a dilemma where the middle of a file name will change but the beginning and end will remain the same. I am trying to store the final result in a variable but I am confused on how to do this.

```
ips=['10.240.10.5','10.232.10.5','10.200.10.5','10.200.10.6','10.232.10.6','10.240.10.6','10.200.10.7','10.200.10.7']

for i in ips:
        sessionFile = 'sdee_sid_' . i[0] . '.data'
        f = open(sessionFile, r)
        subscription = f.read()
```

I am getting errors for the sessionFile variable...

```
File "closeallSDEEsession.py", line 8
    sessionFile = "sdee_sid_" . i[0] . ".data"
                                             ^
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Python uses `+`, not `.`, for string concatenation. It's been about four years since I did any coding in it though. Try `'sdee_sid_' + i[0] + '.data'`?

Comment: This is pretty simple to look up on various areas (a Google search of "python string concatenation" yields how to concatenate strings). Please do some research prior to asking a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no string concatenation operator in python, just use `+`:

```
'sdee_sid_' + i + '.data'
```

or [printf-like string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
'sdee_sid_%s.data' % i
```

or [new-style string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
'sdee_sid_{}.data'.format(i)
```

Note that `i[0]` is the first character of `i`, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Upvote for mentioning `"".format()`

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
sessionFile = 'sdee_sid_' . i[0] . '.data'
```

should be:

```
sessionFile = 'sdee_sid_' + i[0] + '.data'
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
sessionFile = 'sdee_sid_' . i[0] . '.data'
```

to

```
sessionFile = 'sdee_sid_%s.data' % i[0]
```

I also think you want `i` instead of `i[0]` because the latter is the first character of the current string in the list you are iterating over.